# Chrome Extension - External login using SAML 2.0 (Web SSO)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, saml-2.0, login-control

I am to create a Chrome extension which allows the user to login using an external login service. The Chrome Extension is for danish students, and the login service is the public login service Unilogin (every student in Denmark have a login to this service and is a requirement when developing anything to schools in Denmark).

The external login service is running [SAML 2.0 - Web SSO (danish)](https://viden.stil.dk/display/INFRA2/SAML+snitfladebeskrivelse+til+login+og+autentificering)

For OAuth there is [chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow(...)](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/identity#method-launchWebAuthFlow)

How to login to an external SAML in a Chrome Extension?

Comment: Try following this tutorial on how to use [launchWebAuthFlow]() in chrome extension - [Writing a Chrome extension](https://spidergears.wordpress.com/2015/03/27/chrome-browser-extensions/). You can also check [Facebook_Oauth2_sample_for_extensions](https://github.com/blackgirl/Facebook_Oauth2_sample_for_extensions), this app uses the launchWebAuthFlow flow of the Identity API, which is enabling authorization with providers other than Google. Hope this helps.

Comment: The thing is, Facebook uses OAuth2, not SAML. And lhe login provider I am using is SAML. Does  chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow(...) work with both OAuth and SAML?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is not to use SAML, but to use [SSO Proxy](https://viden.stil.dk/display/INFRA2/SSO+Proxy+snitflade+til+login+og+autentificering). This is a lot simpler to work with. SAML is a more complex integration.

SSO Proxy works with chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow(...). Thanks to the support at Uni-login for their help.